# Postgres 2 node cluster setup

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-13

I want to setup 2 node cluster for postgres. How to configure primary and backup for a 2 node cluster I need to know the best way to do it also its necessary configurations.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html

Comment: There can be no reliable high availability solution with 2 nodes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe what can be the best solution for HA ?

Comment: Patroni. But that's opinion based.